# How do I find the HTML file that shows the sub navigation on profile page in Buddypress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, buddypress

check this out
!(http://d3u3luhfiauvsc.cloudfront.net/hello.png)

I need to find the php/html file 
that shows the submenus on the screenshot under the blue tabs
"personal","mentions","favourites".... (on the pic)

```
//This is how the html looks in the source code
<div class="item-list-tabs no-ajax" id="subnav" role="navigation">ev
<ul>
<li id="just-me-personal-li" class="current selected">
<li id="activity-mentions-personal-li">
<a id="activity-mentions" href="http://127.0.0.1/anonSocial2/members/gabriel_regalado/activity/mentions/">
</li>
<li id="activity-favs-personal-li">
<li id="activity-friends-personal-li">
<li id="activity-groups-personal-li">
<li id="activity-filter-select" class="last">
</ul>
</div>
```

I just want to find the php or html file that triggers it.

Comment: `check this out` No thanks. `I just want to find the php ` Good luck with that.

Comment: Is this not possible? buddypress uses the same loop for every child theme created

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks any effort from the OP.

Comment: this question was answered 7 months ago...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frisco inherits lots of files from BP Default. Look in this file:

```
/members/single/profile.php
```

This function  `bp_get_options_nav();` returns that menu.

Comment: THANKS! 
I just noticed there is a php file for every tab.
every tab has a php file, like activity.php or friends.php which contains this function thanks a lot you are the best